# Convert .svg file format to am Image

Tags: c#, svg

I have an .svg file and I need to convert it into an Image.I tried the below code in C#:

```
System.IO.Stream aIconFile = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Interface.Icon_Seen.svg");                   
byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];                   
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())    
{      
  int read;     
  while ((read = aIconFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)      
  {                         
   ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);     
  }                      
  System.Drawing.ImageConverter converter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();                      
  Image aFinalImage = (Image)converter.ConvertFrom(ms.ToArray());    
}
```

ConvertFrom  is giving me an exception that parameter is not valid.

Any Idea whats going on here?

Comment: There is no built-in functionality to convert an SVG to another image format. SVG is a vector graphics format, and the built-in conversions only work with bitmap formats.

Comment: [librsvg](https://developer.gnome.org/rsvg/stable/) is a very fast and reliable library to handle these conversions. It draws to [cairo](https://developer.gnome.org/cairo/stable/), from where you can export to buffers and several image formats.

Answer (score 0):

Aspose Libraries are very powerful for imaging.I suggest that use them . you can do whatever you want with them